# JAVA SSLSocket keyStore and trustStore, bad certificat error

Tags: java, php, ssl, keystore, truststore

I’m currently writing a JAVA app that receive AJAX requests from a PHP server.
I use sockets for this and it works fine with HTTP requests.
But now I would like to do the same thing with HTTPs requests.

So I created a keyStore using cert and RSA key of the website :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <path_to_website_cert> -inkey <path_to_website_rsa_key> -out keystore.p12 -name website -CAfile <path_to_ca_cert> -caname root
```

Then I transformed it in jks :

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass password -alias website
```

I also added the cert to the trustStore :

```
keytool -import -file <path_to_website_cert> -alias website -keystore <path_to_my_jdk>\jre\lib\security\cacerts
```

Here is the code I use to launch my server on my JAVA app :

```
public void lancer_serveur_https() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Users/f.guibert/Documents/Cert/incafu.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Users/f.guibert/Documents/Cert/trustStore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

    try {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(this.port);

        while(true) {
            try {
                SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) ss.accept();
                s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites());

                OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;
                while (((line = in.readLine()) != null) && (!("".equals(line)))) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                out.close();
                in.close();
                s.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After all these steps, when my AJAX request is sent I got this error with JAVA :

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

And an error in my web console (network tab) saying that the cert is only valid for domain :

```
*.mydomain.com, with error code SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN.
```

I’m really stuck with it cause I don’t know what I’m doing wrong. I think there is something I misunderstood with keyStore and trustStore but can’t find what.